# Search NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

Hi what I want to do is search an NSMutable array for the string str or the header label in the view. If the word already exists in the array then I want to delete it. Otherwise I want to add it. Here's my code so far.

```
-(IBAction)add:(id)sender{
  NSMutableArray *array=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] mutableArrayValueForKey:@"favorites"];
  NSString *str=header.text;    
}
```

Comment: And [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) is the reference for NSArray, where all the search functions are.

Answer (score 0):

See the manual: [NSArray Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

Comment: Can you show me what in the reference you would use in a ibaction